# How to insert (flexible) data into S/4HANA from cells in an Excel file with VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I currently have this VBA Code to insert a dataset (which is in an Excel file) into SAP S/4HANA. What happens now with the code is that it has set the values that I have entered, however, I would like the code to go to the Excel cell and read the value that is in the cell so that the insertion of the data in SAP is flexible.

On line 35 where the text appears, this line does not always work as I want... Because in SAP opens type Word file to insert the text.

The date in the text should fetch the month and year from cell `I1`.
I added comments in the code says where the data is in Excel.

```vb
Sub services()

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "FB70"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").Text = "2222"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
'Below value from CELL B4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-ACCNT").Text = "1234567"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-BLDAT").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-BLDAT").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
'Below value from CELL I4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/txtINVFO-WRBTR").Text = "100.00"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/chkINVFO-XMWST").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/chkINVFO-XMWST").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/cmbINVFO-MWSKZ").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/cmbINVFO-MWSKZ").Key = "J3"
'Below value from CELL G4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,0]").Text = "25875000"
'Below value from CELL I4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/txtACGL_ITEM-WRBTR[4,0]").Text = "100.00"
'Below value from CELL H4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-KOSTL[17,0]").Text = "3782000"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-EOBJ[35,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-EOBJ[35,0]").press
'Below value from CELL B4
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLKEAK:0400/ctxtRKEAK-FIELD[0,24]").Text = "1234567"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLKEAK:0400/ctxtRKEAK-FIELD[0,24]").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-LTEXT[12,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-LTEXT[12,0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subNOTICE:SAPLEENO:1001/btnEENO_TEXTE-EDITOR").press
'Below values: The date is in cell I1 (format: month/yyyy) and the text is in cell J4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").setDocument 1, _
"Services about health and security for the month of april/2022"   
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[5]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Print:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VksaG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WorksheetFunction.Text() or Format() functions to convert a date into the desired format. This assumes that field I4 already has a Date format

```
    Sub services()

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
    Set session = objConn.Children(0)
    Dim sht as Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheet1 ' Set your worksheet here
    Dim intRow%
    intRow = 4 ' Set the row number here, or put the below part into a For loop

    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "FB70"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").Text = "2222"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-ACCNT").Text = sht.Range("B" & intRow).Value
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-BLDAT").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-BLDAT").caretPosition = 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/txtINVFO-WRBTR").Text = sht.Range("I" & intRow).Value
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/chkINVFO-XMWST").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/chkINVFO-XMWST").Selected = True
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/cmbINVFO-MWSKZ").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/cmbINVFO-MWSKZ").Key = "J3"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,0]").Text = sht.Range("G" & intRow).Value
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/txtACGL_ITEM-WRBTR[4,0]").Text = sht.Range("I" & intRow).Value
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-KOSTL[17,0]").Text = sht.Range("H" & intRow).Value
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-EOBJ[35,0]").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-EOBJ[35,0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLKEAK:0400/ctxtRKEAK-FIELD[0,24]").Text = sht.Range("B" & intRow).Value
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLKEAK:0400/ctxtRKEAK-FIELD[0,24]").caretPosition = 7 ' You can remove this, it just puts the caret after the 7th character, which might fail if the value is shorter
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-LTEXT[12,0]").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM-LTEXT[12,0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subNOTICE:SAPLEENO:1001/btnEENO_TEXTE-EDITOR").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").setDocument 1, WorksheetFunction.Text(sht.Range("J" & intRow).Value, """Services about health and security for the month of"" mmmm\/YYYY")
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[5]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press


End Sub
```

If you want to force the month name to be in English, use `WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheet2.Range("C2").Value, "[$-409]""Services about health and security for the month of"" mmmm\/YYYY")`

Comment: running the command does everything right up to the point that it displays the text I want to add. What do I change in the code to only get the text that is in cell J$4 (without the fixed text between "")? 
Currently, when I run the code I get the following option (I added a print in the question)

Comment: as I used a concatenate function, I no longer need to fetch the date cell (I1), but I now need to fetch the full text in cell J4

Comment: If you need just the text, use `sht.Range("J" & intRow).Value`